# Issue On Setting Element CSS Left By Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This code simply using a `.css()` in jQuery to center element is the page. This is setting the vertical centering but the horizontal (left) is not working (Please be ware that I already knew there is a `text-align:center` rule in CSS to to do this by element parent, but I really need to know why jquery is not doing now?!)

```
var elemntHeight = $("h1").height();
var elementWidth =  $("h1").width();

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var windowWidth  = $(window).width();

$("h1").css({
    "position" : "absolute",
    "left" :  windowWidth /2 - elementWidth/2,
    "top":  windowHeight/2 - elemntHeight /2
});
```

can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: You have to add some measurement value like `px` or whatever. `"left" :  windowWidth /2 - elementWidth/2 +"px"`

Comment: @Vucko, thanks for reply buto why the to setting is working fine?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Changing the positioning of an element may change its dimensions

Comment: sure , there you are http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/MLgU5/

Comment: `h1` is a **block** element which means it will take all of the parents width, so in your example - the `body` width. Add `h1{display:inline-block}` and it will work - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLgU5/3/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MLgU5/2/

Comment: @ hi Musa thanks but as you can see I already have the Position absolute in my.css() how come it is not doing the job?

Comment: @Suffii - Vucko's answer is correct regarding the `block` element. By defining position:absolute in your CSS, the script evaluates WITHOUT the full width of its parent (because it's been removed from the DOM flow due to positioning) - otherwise, it uses 100% of the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On load your h1 is actually 100% wide so the Left directove *is* working -- it's just that's it's only indenting by 8px

Stick a `h1{border: 1px solid red;}` into the css of your fiddle and you'll see

Comment: The 8px is the _margin_ from `body`. Add `body{margin:0}` and it will be removed and the `h1` will have `left:0px`.